# CiviCRM Frontend or Public-Facing Page 404 Not Found

Tags: wordpress, base-page

It seems that all of CiviCRM frontend/public-facing pages are not working for me, they either redirect to the homepage (Petition), or throws a 404 not found (Other pages like Profile Create Mode & Mailing).

I have:

1. Created a blank base page named "CMS" and use the base page in **Administer > System Settings > CMS Database Integration**.
2. Set all permission for public/guest viewing in **Users and Permissions > Permissions (Access Control) > WordPress Access Control**

If I insert the Profile forms manually on their own page, they work fine and I can view/submit the form.

CiviCRM Installation Details:

- WordPress 5.5.1
- CiviCRM 5.24.6

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on wordpress 5.24 you need to have civicrm 5.26 or more. Would recommend to upgrade your CiviCRM to 5.28.4